# Connection string error.. provider name?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hello I am getting this error and can't seem to figure out what may be wrong. I think it might have something to do with the provider name but its throwing me errors.

> Error'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' and no extension method
>   'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment]" 
    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is what the datasource looks like. and my web config looks like this.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=mydatasource;Persist Security Info=True;Password=mypass;User ID=myuser;Initial Catalog=mycatalog"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

my connection manager looks like this

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);




    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl values('" + generateidtxt.Text + "','" + hawbtxt.Text + "','" + invrefpotxt.Text + "','" + hppartnumtxt.Text + "','" + iecpartnumtxt.Text + "','" + qtytxt.Text + "','" + bulkstxt.Text + "','" + boxplttxt.Text + "','" + rcvddatetxt.Text + "','" + statustxt.Text + "','" + carriertxt.Text + "','" + shippertxt.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Your DATA stored Successfully!";
        hawbtxt.Text = "";
        invrefpotxt.Text = "";
        hppartnumtxt.Text = "";
        iecpartnumtxt.Text = "";
        qtytxt.Text = "";
        bulkstxt.Text = "";
        boxplttxt.Text = "";
        rcvddatetxt.Text = "";
        statustxt.Text = "";
        carriertxt.Text = "";
        shippertxt.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: _Java_ and _JavaScript_ are similar to the eye but different languages. Have you tagged this question correctly?

Comment: @PaulS.: Neither; this question is about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Web.config defines an OleDb connection string (for the OleDb engine) that uses the SQL Server OleDb provider to connect to SQL Server through OleDb.

Your code then passes that connection string to a **Sql**Connection, which connects directly to SQL Server using the SQL native client and uses a completely different connection string.

You should change Web.config to use `System.Data.SqlClient` and its connection string format.  (this is more efficient than OleDb)

Comment: Hmm... okay. Is there any way you can explain how to do this step by step?

Comment: Change the providerName in Web.config to `System.Data.SqlClient` and build the appropriate connection string for SQL client.  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server

Comment: Because I'm using visual studios 2008 with sql server 2012. And when I try to make the sql connection to vs it tells me "This server version is not supported.. only servers up to microsoft sql server 2005 are supported."

Answer (score 3):

As the error *clearly* states, you don't have any `SqlDataSource1_Selecting` method (for the `onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"` event handler)

Comment: What would you suggest I do to fix the error? I know what it says I just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @user2457203 You need to create the `SqlDataSource1_Selecting` method in your code so that it can be called when needed.

Comment: Or don't handle the event at all.

Comment: Hmm.. okay I just deleted the onselecting. I don't think I need it.. now i'm getting an error saying keyword not supported :'provider' this would be on the first connectionmanager line. http://puu.sh/39MDb.png